# Script for changing one line of *.csv file for a whole directory of files?

Tags: python, datetime, batch-file, csv, ubuntu

I have a question about writing a command prompt script (DOS) in Windows 7.

The task I have:
I have a directory of raw data files (*.csv) where the 38th line is where the date and time are saved.
Example File cell A38:
    Start Date/Time: 6/20/2014 13:26:16

However, this date format is M/DD/YYYY because it was saved using a sampling computer where the date of the computer was set-up as such.
I know there is a way to write a script that can be executed on a directory of these files so that none of the other information (text or actual time stamp) is changed,
but the Date format switched to the UK style of DD/MM/YYYY.

Intended product:
The file is unchanged in any way but line 38 reads
    Start Date/Time: 20/06/2014 13:26:16

I really do not want to go through and do this to 800 plus files, and more coming, so any help would be very appreciated in helping do this format change
in a script format that could be executed on the entire directory of *.csv files.

I also think it is an important note that the entire text as well as the actual date and time are in one Cell in Excel (A38)  (Start Date/Time: M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS)
and that I DO want to keep the time as 24hour time.

Any guidance/pointers would be great. I am very new to command line programming in Windows. Also happy to see if such a script is available for an Ubuntu environment, or a python script, or anything really that would automate this tedious task of changing one part of one line close to 1000 times, as switching the changed directory back to the Windows computer is no big deal at all. Just easier (and Im sure possible using cmd.exe)

Cheers,
Wal

Comment: are there only .csv files in the dir?

Comment: Pointer: Try writing it yourself and if you have problems, _then_ post a question here with the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

So your options, roughly, are:

- Python
- Windows 'cmd' script
- Transfer the files to a *nix environment and do it there with those tools if you are more familiar

If using Python, look at:

- the `os` module, `os.listdir()`, `os.path` etc.
- Regex replace using a function (`re.sub` taking a function rather than a string as a replacement)
- `datetime.datetime.strptime` and `datetime.datetime.strftime`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a sample file, but `sed` should be something like...

```
sed /(.*?,){37}/ s/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/\2\/\1\/\3/
```

And you could do it en masse by doing:

```
for file in /path/to/files/*.csv
do
    sed -ri".bak" /(.*?,){37}/ s/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/\2\/\1\/\3/ file
done
```

Tested now on GnuWin32's sed.

```
# INFILE @ /test/a.csv
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2/20/2014
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12/31/2014
# INFILE @ /test/b.csv
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,7/11/2014
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5/18/1987

# Command line command
C:\>FOR %f IN (C:\test\*.csv) DO sed -ri".bak" "/(.*?,){37}/ s/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/\2\/\1\/\3/" %f

# OUTFILE @ /test/a.csv
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,20/2/2014
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,31/12/2014
# OUTFILE @ /test/b.csv
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,11/7/2014
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,18/5/1987
```